# Python Selenium: Automating Chrome Extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible that my python script opens up Chrome Browser, Navigate a Page and then hit the Chrome Extension button in top bar to display certain things?

The extension injects a DIV within Amazon Page with Data.

Comment: Yes, it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057048/automate-a-button-click-on-chrome-extensions-page-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: how does it solve my issue?

Comment: I'd try to set up a key stroke in your extension and trigger it with selenium

Comment: @minj Ext is a 3rd party app