# How to send KeyStrokes to Chrome Browser?

Tags: c#, python-2.7, winapi, google-chrome-extension

I want to click the Chrome Extension button . Is it possible? I'd be using it on Windows based machine. I know it is not possible via Selenium but Win32 API could do it.

I am not restricted to language so both c# and python could work.

Comment: See if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057048/automate-a-button-click-on-chrome-extensions-page-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: [chrome.automation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/automation)