# How to load extension with hotkey to webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, hotkeys

I'd like to start an extension(unpacked) by its hotkey in Chrome via Webdriver. I'm not able to have the hotkey/shortkey in the running ChromeDriver instance. Can someone tell me, how to do this?
This is the code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("load-extension=C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\blablabla\\4.3.25_0")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This inits a new Chrome with the extension, but the original hotkey isn't included. My idea is to add some Option or Capability or prefs, but haven't found anything similar yet.
It would also be OK if I could create a new profile, install the extension, set the hotkey, and start Chrome with this profile, but I need those profile creating steps programatically, also.
Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: [How to send Keyboard Shortcuts to browser using Selenium and Nodejs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12753) - `WebDriver cannot be used todo browser specific actions, it can only be used to drive the web-page` so you'll have to send the hotkey using python, there should be lots of googlable examples.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but the question is not how to send hotkey press, it can be easily done with pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v') for example. The question is, how to set up the added extension so that it contains a hotkey that can start it via Python. Any idea on this?

Comment: I see. Try [Automate a button click on chrome://extensions page using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073565) - navigate to `chrome://extensions`, find and click the `shortcuts` link, find and click your extension's hotkey input box, make sure the window is active and send a hotkey using pyautogui. Also note, the extension must have a `browserAction` or `commands` key in its manifest.

Comment: @wOxxOm Would you please not write what amounts to extended answers in comments?

Comment: Obviously that's just a guess based on blind googling. With redundant explanations to avoid 'what do u mean' followups. Calling it an extended answer is a superoverexaggeration.

Comment: Based on your idea, I could open the chrome://extensions-frame with webdriver, and handle it with selenium. The hotkey is set, however, pyautogui.hotkey won't work :( I guess it is some windows limitation, so I'll investigate more on this. Thank you! On the other hand, I think my question was clear, I needed the loaded extension to contain a hotkey configured to start it. So why not copy your comment to an answer? ;) /link wasn't needed, however/

Comment: My comment is just a hint. It'd be better if you post an answer that actually solves the problem so that the hotkey works.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added an answer that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the question (I eliminated any command that was not with WebDriver, for example pyautogui.hotkey, etc):

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("load-extension=" + ext_folder)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
browser.get('chrome://extensions-frame/')
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='extension-commands-config']").click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='command-shortcut-text']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "m")
browser.find_element(By.ID, "extension-commands-dismiss").click()

browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "m")
```

Comment: I have written below code : driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://extensions-frame/"); driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='extension-commands-config']")).Click(); driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='command-shortcut-text']")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "m"); driver.FindElement(By.Id("extension-commands-dismiss")) .Click(); i am getting error like OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='extension-commands-config']"}. Please help in this.